# typescript set default for a function passed as an argument to another function

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to set a default for a function passed as an argument to another function. By default i mean a function that does absolutely nothing.

So i can check if the function argument value is null and assign it to an empty void function:

```
MyFunction(someVar:string,callback:()=>void){
 if(callback==null) {this.MyEmptyFunction();}else{callback();}
```

}

```
MyEmptyFunction():void{}
```

Is a way to avoid creating an empty function and the `null` check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a default just as you would for any other parameter:

```
function MyFunction(someVar:string, callback = () => { }){
    callback();
}
```

Or with the argument type explicitly specified:

```
function MyFunction(someVar: string, callback: () => void = () => { }) {
    callback();
}
```